# Using the chain rule to find derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could you help me figure this one out?

$$f(x) = 6e^{x\sin x}$$

$$f'(x) = \,?$$

Answer (score 10):

A more direct way, without the logarithms approach in my other posted answer:
\begin{align}\frac d{dx}(6e^{x \sin x})&= 6 \frac d{dx}e^{x\sin x} \\
&=6e^{x \sin x} \frac d{dx}(x \sin x) & \text{chain rule} \\
&=\boxed{6e^{x \sin x}(\sin x + x \cos x)} & \text{product rule}\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for this one. This really helped me fully understand how you get the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Add logarithms to both sides of the equation $f(x) = 6e^{x \sin x}$

\begin{align}\ln f(x) &= \ln (6e^{x \sin x}) \\
&= \ln 6 + \ln e^{x \sin x} \\
&= \ln 6 + x \sin x,
\end{align}

and implicitly differentiate both sides to get

\begin{align}
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sin x + x \cos x.
\end{align}

Finally, we get
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=f(x)(\sin x + x \cos x) \\ &= \boxed{6e^{x \sin x}(\sin x + x \cos x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Should be an $x$ attached to that $\cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

Take things step-by-step:

Chain rule applies when you have a function of the form $f(x) = g(h(x))$.  So what is $g(x)$ in this case?  What is $h(x)$?

From there, we know $f'(x) = g'(h(x)) \cdot h'(x)$.  In computing $h'(x)$, you may need to apply the product rule, so be cautious.

Comment: Is h(x)=6e and g(x) = xsinx?

Thank you for the answer

Comment: Close.  $g(x) = 6e^x$, and $h(x) = x\sin(x)$.  Composing these with each other, you should verify that you actually get $f(x)$ back.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In the context of the exponential function, the chain rule says
$$\left(e^{\square}\right)' =e^{\square}\cdot \square'$$

Now fill in the box with what is in your problem.

Also, don't forget the multiplier of $6$ out front, but that's easy. That just tags along as a multiplier in the end.

Answer (score 1):

$(x\sin x)'=\sin x+x\cos x$, so $(6e^{x\sin x})'=6(\sin x+x\cos x)e^{x\sin x}$.